# <iframe> instead of include

Tags: php, iframe, include, comments

I want to include multiple comments sections on one page using the [Commentics](http://www.commentics.org/) php sript.
First I tried accomplishing this using `include` like so:

```
<div id="1">  
    <?php  
    include "comments_id1.php";  
    ?>  
</div>  
<div id="2">  
    <?php  
    include "comments_id2.php";  
    ?>  
</div>
```

comments_id1.php:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
ob_start();
?>
[...]
<?php 
$page_id = "1"; 
$reference = "Page One"; 
$path_to_comments_folder = "comments/"; 
define ('IN_COMMENTICS', 'true');
require $path_to_comments_folder . "includes/commentics.php";
?>
```

(comments_id2.php accordingly: `$page_id = "2"; $reference = "Page Two"`)

Apparently (and it might be worth noting that I'm still pretty clueless when it comes to PHP), this doesn't work or at least leads to all kinds of troubles (e.g. "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent").

So the solution I came up with was using the `<iframe>` tag, like so:

```
<div id="1">  
    <iframe width="100%" src="comments_id1.php"></iframe> 
</div>  
<div id="2">  
    <iframe width="100%" src="comments_id2.php"></iframe>  
</div>
```

Now here's my question:
Is this even a valid solution that anyone would recommend? And if so are there any major consequences (besides search engines) using `<iframe>` for that purpose?
If this is not the way to go, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Personally I deeply hate IFRAMEs for may reasons, so I'd recommend to stay away from them.

Have you read the [Commentics' integration guide](http://www.commentics.org/integration.php)?

It seems you have to put

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
?>
```

at the beginning of the pag, and

```
<?php
    $page_id = "1";
    $reference = "Page One";
    $path_to_comments_folder = "comments/";
    define ('IN_COMMENTICS', 'true'); //no need to edit this line
    require $path_to_comments_folder . "includes/commentics.php"; //no need to edit this line
?>
```

where you want your comments. There's also an [extended integration guide](http://www.commentics.org/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation%3aintegration).

Comment: That only works for one comment section, when I add another one on the same page it doesn't show up and the page stops loading from where that second comment section would be (no PHP errors, though).

Comment: Also, judging by this thread http://www.commentics.org/forum/showthread.php?tid=55 on the Commentics support forums it's generally not possible to have multiple comments sections on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't use iframes …

to work around the headers problem, you can buffer output (headers can only be sent before the actual content) and then send all at once:

```
ob_start();
// your code with includes
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: This would be in the main page right? Not in the the individual comments pages. I can't get it to work anyway. Although the header doesn't seem to be the problem, because I don't get that warning anymore somehow. Now I don't get any errors at all – it just stops loading after the second include.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the script you're using, but iframes have some significant downsides. Some downsides to that approach could be:

- Iframes need their width and height defined in the HTML tag. If the dimensions inside the Iframe differ (because of an longer than usual comment, for example), you would get extra set(s) of scrollbars.
- The memory usage and render times of iframes are high, especially in older Internet Explorer versions

To avoid the "Cannot modify header information" warnings, you could enable [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) in PHP, or you could look at what headers the script you're using is actually sending. Maybe they're unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Another consequence of using iframes is that the rendering may be out of order, since it is an independent HTTP request, and, because it is an additional request, this can add overall time to the retrieval of the data, especially in IE versions before 8 where they were limited to 2 simultaneous HTTP requests at a time--so if you have images or other scripts loading at the same time, some of these may be queued until one or both of the two slots are free. IE8 (and Firefox) boosted this to 6.

While it seems the real solution is looking into them fixing the Commentics script, or you finding another library, despite all advice you will probably find here to the contrary (albeit for good reasons of course), for beginners, I recommend focused on practicality and experimentation rather than dogma; in other words, it could work out all right for you, as long as there are no links inside the iframes which, if clicked, would lead to only the iframe being replaced with the content. Not a best practice though for reasons I and others have mentioned.

Another issue to watch for is that even the slightest whitespace before your beginning `<?php` is interpreted as text sent to the user, so if a script you include tries to then add headers, you could have problems. The headers being already sent message means that the script has started to send headers since it needed to send them before starting to send the content (in this case the whitespace) which you already started printing out (without buffering).

For PHP, I really recommend a templating engine like Smarty (and Smarty is nicely documented) where you get comfortable with the pattern of letting your business logic run first, and then supplying variables to the design logic for use there (currently what is your HTML + includes). When you're including others libraries which output text, you will need to still use buffering though for such reasons as you discovered.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I will have to abandon my concept of multiple comments at least until I have a deeper understanding of PHP or I find a script that will do that. I wasn't really keen on using iframes in the first place but it was the only way it would work. And since everyone's advice here is to keep my hands off iframes, I will. Smarty was on my list of things to look into anyway, so I'm going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
?>
```

from comments_id1.php

It will work.